# Advice for a search function that will search multiple tables? - PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, search

In my web application I am planning to include a Search field which will allow users to enter a string.

This string will then be used to compare against rows of data in multiple tables for example in this database. (this is just an example, in the real problem there is about 20 tables).

**Table List:**

- Customer
- Books
- Paintings

What is the best way to do a search, as this is my first time doing one that would look over multiple tables?

Do you just go through the tables sequentially comparing each row to the search string or can you make a query that searches the whole database in general?

Should you stop the search once you found a exact match or do you just continue the search regardless if you found a match? Incase there are multiple rows of the same type?

I would like to do this in the most "correct" way possible I had a look at some examples but they only seem to relate to one or two table searches.

I have this pseudo code in my head for what I might do so if you could give me feedback on that too

```
Get string from $_POST['search'] 
Strip string of special characters that could be used for Mysql injection.
Connect to db 
Search first table for row that is LIKE string
If match found then add to result object
Search next table, and repeat.
When finished search disconnect from DB.
```

So I hope you lot will be able to guide me link to materials so I can implement this piece of functionality as best as possible.

Thankyou :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let you know that this will become in an very poor performance search if search condition is 'contains' but not `starts with`. Also that indexes are needed for all searchables columns.

Whell, the most easy way to do this query is to make a big view with an union of all search fields:

```
create view my_search as (
   select 
     id_customer as key, 
     customer_name as value, 
     'customers' as table,
     1 as priority
   from customer
   UNION ALL
   select 
     id_customer as key, 
     customer_alternate_name as value, 
     'customers' as table,
     2 as priority
   from customer
   UNION ALL
   ...
   UNION ALL
   select 
     id_Paintings as key, 
     Paintings_name as value, 
     'Paintings' as table,
     8 as priority
   from Paintings
)
```

Then perform query over view:

```
select * from my_search
 where value like ...
 order by priority
```

Notice that this don't solve your requeriment to get results only from first table where string appears, you can stop php fetching rows when priority change is found.

Comment: Hi this code does not run on Mysql 5.05, is this for a different DBMS?

Comment: Sorry, untested code, please, let me know error to fix the query!

Comment: its saying there is a MySQL Syntax Error on line 3 - "id_customer as key, " it does not like the "key" part i think

Comment: Oh, sorry, key should be a reserved word. Change it to my_key or enclose in quotes (reverse quotes)

Answer (score 1):

No easy way to go about this other than searching each table individually.

You could union them in a single select I guess but I would highly discourage you from doing so.

Why don't you look for a search solution such as Lucene Solr (http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or Sphinx (http://sphinxsearch.com/) instead? I've done this in the past with great success.

Comment: Mobius, why are unions bad could you send me some links to explain why they are not good. Thanks

Comment: @loosebruce It's not that unions are bad, it's the logic behind using a union that I think it's bad. You are combining different tables under one column name, this makes it hard to maintain when you need to change stuff in your application/database structure. Also bear in mind that putting such unions in views is also bad since you cannot index views [(see here)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-restrictions.html) thus resulting in eventually poor performance

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'd be interested to see the database design - from the examples you have there I think there may well be a better design. I don't know if your examples are actual tables, but if you are using those, what differences do the tables actually have?

Whenever you find yourself looking through 20 tables for the same field, you have to ask yourself if what you're doing is absolutely the only way, or whether you've got something wrong in the database design, or indeed are looking at the problem in the wrong way.

All that said, if you absolutely must have them orgainsed like this, then you can search multiple tables at once, albeit in an unpleasant way - see the answer from danihp for an example of using UNION to get the data you want.

I'd imagine you should be looking at the database and not the code for changes, though, although I may be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, basically my database is a a quote system for customers. The idea is that with my search function the user will be able to track down a customer using many ways, e.g. quoteid, what items they are associated to, their business type. their name. their company name, their bill/invoice no. etc.

Comment: Sounds like that I might have been wrong, then - I was mainly concerned that you had 20 tables, half or more of which were all different types of product, all with the same columns. If you have 20 genuinely different tables storing totally different data in each then you've probably got a legitimate reason to go for this search. From the comment it seems like you do, so as I say, danihp's solution seems good.